# fetch user data from server flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm following this tutorial from devs [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) to fetch data from internet but I can't decode response to `User` object.

Since I'm using `Postman` to check API I can tell you that my request is successfully received and server responses me with `200` and a body full of data (`name`, `id` and `token`) but when I try to call `fromJson` method inside `try-catch` block to create `User` object it fails and this error is printed :

```
flutter: Response 200
flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

This is my User class :

```
  class User extends Equatable {
  final String token;
  final String name;
  final String id;

  const User({
    required this.token,
    required this.name,
    required this.id,
  });

  static const User empty = User(token: "token", name: "name", id: "id");

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, String>{
      'token': token,
      'name': name,
      'id': id,
    };
  }

  factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      token: json['token'] ?? "token",
      name: json['name'] ?? "name",
      id: json['id'] ?? "id",
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) => User.fromMap(jsonMap);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return token + ' ' + name + ' ' + id + '\n';
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [token, name, id];
}
```

`UserCredentials` that's just a wrapper for username and password :

```
class UserCredentials {
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String password;
  UserCredentials(
      {required this.name, required this.email, required this.password});

  factory UserCredentials.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserCredentials(
      name: json['name'] as String,
      email: json['email'] as String,
      password: json['password'] as String,
    );
  }
  Map<String, String> toJsonRegistration() {
    return {
      "name": name,
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
    };
  }

  Map<String, String> toJsonLogin() {
    return {
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return name + " " + email + " " + password + '\n';
  }
}
```

And this is my `user_repository` function used to get data from server :

```
     Future<User> _login(UserCredentials user) async {
    User? userFetched;
    //print(user);
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://link_to_repo"),
      body: user.toJsonLogin(),
    );
    print("Inizio");
    print((response.body));
    print(jsonDecode(response.body));
    print(User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)));
    print("fine");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      try {
        userFetched = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        print(userFetched);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
      print("End");
      return userFetched!;
    } else {
      print("Login Failure from repository");
      throw Exception("Email already taken");
    }
  }
```

As you seen above it's able to print "Response 200" but not to complete successfully the operation inside `try-catch` block.

Edit :

This is the `response.body` :

```
{"data" : {"token":"50|IUMNqKgc7Vffmz8elRd0MIZeSyuEgHL418KwQ0Jz","name":"test","id":1}}
```

And `jsonDecode(response.body))` :

```
{data: {token: 50|IUMNqKgc7Vffmz8elRd0MIZeSyuEgHL418KwQ0Jz, name: test, id: 1}}
```

Solution :

This post is a little confusing but to be clear :

`Clucera` gave me the exact solution to fetch the data and create `User` object so I accepted its answers.

`Josip Domazet`'s answer helped me fixing the error but he didn't solve the problem because I still couldn't create `User` data.

Comment: You have edited the original question to already fix the error that you are asking about. @CLucera fixed your second error that was caused by some fields that you are accessing being null (because they are deeper in the json). I fixed the original type error that you got. Those are different questions. Please edit your question to include that information, otherwhise future readers will be confused by this. Thanks.

Comment: My need was to create a User, you helped me only fixing the error. I forgot to upvote your answer but now I did it, that was useful but I cannot accept it as solution this is the best that I can do.

Comment: its fine, thank you. I was more thinking of not confusing future readers but I think they will figure it out when they read the comments. Posting an error message in a question but then editing the code that caused it can be quite misleading at times ^^

Comment: Yeah I'll learn for the future, when is hard to understand what's happening is easy to create more confusion :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it looks like you are doing the following

```
User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

and from there you are creating the User instance with the following factory

```
 factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      token: json['token'] ?? "token",
      name: json['name'] ?? "name",
      id: json['id'] ?? "id",
  );
```

The issue is that your Json is contained in another json called "data" as your print response show

```
{data: {token: 50|IUMNqKgc7Vffmz8elRd0MIZeSyuEgHL418KwQ0Jz, name: test, id: 1}}
```

in this case you have two solution, either you nest the keys inside your constructor (don't suggest you this approach)

```
 factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      token: json['data']['token'] ?? "token",
      name: json['data']['name'] ?? "name",
      id: json['data']['id'] ?? "id",
  );
```

Or where you parse the json you can extract directly the `data` json (I suggest you this option)

```
User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)['data']);
```

Answer (score 1):

`jsonDecode(response.body)` will return a `Map`. However your constructor `User.fromJson` takes a `String` as argument. Decoding it once is enough and from then on your can work with the `Map` you already have. So no need to call `jsonDecode` again in `fromJson`, this should work fine:

```dart
 factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) =>
      User.fromMap(jsonMap);
```

If we look at your exception it tell us just that:

```dart
flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Your constructor expects a `String` but received a Map (`_InternalLinkedHashMap`).

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, still have the same error : 
flutter: Response 200
flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'

Comment: @FinleyAdams Edited my answer. Try  `Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap` instead of `Map<String, String> jsonMap`.

Comment: flutter: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' :(

Comment: @FinleyAdams alright I think we fixed that one. This new error is probably caused by `json['token']` or some other fields that you access being null (and not a `String`). Please post the entire stack trace in your question if you need more help.

Comment: I don't have a stack trace, nothing is printed that's why I'm going crazy. The only thing displayed in terminal are my prints

Comment: @FinleyAdams Stay calm I had that kind of error a dozen times ^^ Print `json['token']`,  `json['name']`, `json['id']` before you actually use them. In the print statements make sure that all of them are set. Some of them are probably `Null`, hence the error.

Comment: Post print(response.body); as an example what to expect.

Comment: @user18309290 I added some print in original post